# Android Device Manager lock doesn't prompt for password

Tags: android-device-manager, samsung-galaxy-s7

My phone stopped taking my normal password all of a sudden, so I'm using Android Device Manager to set a new password.  Android Device Manager is working fine and allowing me to call my phone and change the message on the lock screen.

However, the screen won't let me input any sort of password to login.  If I hit the Android back button, it takes me to the standard unlock screen, but that screen won't accept my password.

How do I get back into my phone after setting a Lock in Android Device Manager?

(I'm on a Samsung Galaxy S7 if it matters)

Answer (score 0):

I never got to the point where I could enter the temporary lock password.  However, I later powered-off, waited a few seconds, and powered back on.  At that point, my old password still worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow Device Manager to access the phone while you still have access to it (a little like allowing an app to access a feature on your phone).

There is also a Samsung-related program, which, if you have a Samsung account linked on your phone, you can use to get in (via Kies maybe?).

After-the-fact, it seems like the only options are to factory reset, flash new firmware (possibly blocked by bootloader locks), or sideload an exploit in Download Mode.